# Where should I install CMake?

Tags: python-2.7, cmake

I am trying to pip install dlib for a project I am working on, but when I try I get this error:

> RuntimeError: CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: dlib

I tried to install CMake, but couldn't understand where should I locate the extracted files?

Answer (score 30):

Here is the main thread solution of this error https://stackoverflow.com/a/52564257/7060530

I ran into this issue as well. I am using **windows** and have a **python** environment that I am installing the requirements to.

I ran `pip install cmake` , and then `pip install dlib`. I no longer received the error and successfully installed dlib.

Comment: I wondered how do I install cmake since I once noticed an `.exe` version of it. But nice one! This worked like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

if you are using conda follow below command

```
conda install -c conda-forge dlib
```

Answer (score 4):

Before installing dlib you need to install prerequisites (cmake, libgtk-3-dev, libboost-all-dev)

If you are using Ubuntu you can install them from terminal

> sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake
>
> sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
>
> sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev

For MACOS you can follow this tutorial

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/03/27/how-to-install-dlib/

Answer (score 1):

Download " Binary distributions " with your system OS version from this link. Add install cmake to your system environment variable. Everything will be okay. It worked for me.

https://cmake.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

You can find [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dlib/18.17.100) the download and all the details.

Comment: thanks, but now i get this error trying to install dlib:   error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-7sowfz\dlib\build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.10.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
        Done Building Project "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-7sowfz\dlib\build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.10.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Comment: idk how can i fix this

Comment: Install the SDK like it said. [link](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation)

Comment: thanks again, but I just don't know what to say. after every error that is fixed, a new one appears

Comment: -- Building for: Visual Studio 14 2015
    -- The C compiler identification is unknown
    -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
    CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
      No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

Comment: any idea what to do with that?

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues/706) ;down bellow there are 2 solutions.