# pip install face_recognition giving error

Tags: python, face-recognition

RuntimeError:

---

CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: dlib

---

---

Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib

Comment: What is your question? Please don't just dump an error message here. Esspecially when the error message has a clear message: `CMake must be installed`. Make sure to indicate where your specific problem is

Comment: Actually when i am trying to pip install face_recognition package on my windows machine, i am getting error `CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: dlib`. Then i pip install CMake and then ran pip install face_recognition again but still getting same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [where should i install CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48503646/where-should-i-install-cmake)

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this issue as well. I am using **windows** and have a **python** environment that I am installing the requirements to.

I ran `pip install cmake` , and then `pip install dlib`. I no longer received the error and successfully installed dlib.

Answer (score 2):

1. first install dlib file manually - download file from [here](https://github.com/RvTechiNNovate/face_recog_dlib_file)
2. then install cmake
3. install face-recognition

just go and [watch the full video](https://youtu.be/jjRFCTmK2SY)

Comment: Please be careful with linking to your own content on different sites, you don't want to be a [spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). You should be including the majority of the content here, and use the link only as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. For those who deals with it now -

Firstly you have to install visual studio, 
and than install there the extension "tools for CMake". 
Look at the installation part here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Only after that you will be able to pip install this package.

So:

1. Install VS
2. Install the extension "tools for CMake"
3. Of course you should also have the python interpreter installed
4. In the command line:

   - pip install CMake
   - pip install face_recognition

**Edit:** 
Not checked, 
but if you don't have Visual Studio installed, try install "CMake Tools" separately, maybe from here: 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vector-of-bool.cmake-tools

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated

Follow these steps from the start.

1 - Downgrade to python 3.6.8.

2 - Install visual studio UPDATE 3

> People usually have visual studio 2015 and the process still doesn't work
>   and the reason is the update. You have to update it to update 3.

OR

> Install visual studio 2015 Update 3 from [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691129)

Now, some people have already installed VS 2015 so **how to update**?

> Launch Visual Studio > Tools > Extensions And Updates > New Window Will open, navigate left and click on Updates > Update

3 - Download and install CMake from [here](https://cmake.org/download/). During installation, Check the Add To Path CheckBox.

4 - pip install cmake

5 - pip install face_recognition