# OpenCV Python Building wheel for dlib (setup.py)

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, pip, setup.py

I am trying to install face_recognition on Ubuntu.

I keep running into this loop, which goes on forever. Please help.

```
pip install face_recognition
Collecting face_recognition
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3f/ed/ad9a28042f373d4633fc8b49109b623597d6f193d3bbbef7780a5ee8eef2/face_recognition-1.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Pillow (from face_recognition)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c1/e6/ce127fa0ac17775bc7887c432ffe945c49ae141f01b477b7cd5e63b16bb5/Pillow-6.0.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from face_recognition) (1.16.3)
Collecting Click>=6.0 (from face_recognition)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fa/37/45185cb5abbc30d7257104c434fe0b07e5a195a6847506c074527aa599ec/Click-7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting face-recognition-models>=0.3.0 (from face_recognition)
Collecting dlib>=19.7 (from face_recognition)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/57/e8a8caa3c89a27f80bc78da39c423e2553f482a3705adc619176a3a24b36/dlib-19.17.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) .
```

Comment: Are you sure you posted the complete error log? If yes, can you run `pip install face_recognition -vvv` and add the output to the question?

Comment: Hey! Thanks i tried that and the loop did not happen again! It installed perfectly. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: If the comment has helped you, you can turn it into an answer yourself. Give more details and explanation to make a good answer.

Comment: @Yunnosch @mshahiddev the reason I didn't add an answer is that there is no answer :-) `pip install -vvv` is just the verbose version of `pip install` - I asked for the output to get more info about the error context. Since running it has "solved" the issue, I suppose there wasn't an issue in the first place and the repeated installation ran faster because of reusing the built cache.

Comment: Basically, the real "answer" to this issue is to be patient - `dlib` builds lots of C++ extensions, so while the command is busy, there's nothing else to do, other than closing other applications or trying the installation out on a more powerful hardware.

Comment: @hoefling i agree with you. I was stuck on a similar supposed 'loop' and it was taking ages to install. The verbose option helped me see the installation file by file and thus realize that i should just be patient!

Answer (score 11):

Add `-vvv` to see if the installation is progressing.

I also was in that loop, it took a long time but it finished.

```
pip install dlib -vvv
```

Answer (score 1):

this is my step-by-step solution

```
    apt-get update
    apt-get install build-essential cmake
    apt-get install libopenblas-dev liblapack-dev 
    apt-get install libx11-dev libgtk-3-dev
    apt-get install python python-dev python-pip
    apt-get install python3 python3-dev python3-pip
```

then install dlib

```
    cd ~
    mkdir temp
    cd temp
    git clone https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git
    cd dlib
    mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..; cmake --build .
    cd ..
    python3 setup.py install
```

then install face_recognition

```
    pip3 install numpy scipy matplotlib pandas face_recognition
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know the cause of the loop, I found a workaround by creating a (Anaconda) container with python version 3.6.9 (whereas at first I tried to install face_recognition with python version 3.7.3. Hope it helps.