# Getting error while installing python package dlib and face_recognition

Tags: python

I wanted to install face_recognition python package which gave me an error which i described below. so i followed this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52564257/19291976 guide but after installing cmake successfully .i ran pip install dlib but i gave me error which is same as error i got while installing face_recognition which i'm not abel to figure out.

error :

ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
Failed to build dlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects