# Not able to download face_recognition package

Tags: python, pip, face-recognition

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlRw4.png)
Error:CMake must be installed to build dlib

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where should I install CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48503646/where-should-i-install-cmake)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Dlib and Cmake C++ tools for windows is needed and it is included with visual studio.

Check out this link: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-install-dlib-library-for-python-in-windows-10-57348ba1117f

After you install dlib, you run 'pip install face-recognition'